# Deleted user content by accident

Tags: user-account, folders, macos

I was trying to empty the trash from terminal because Xcode was stuck in it, but I accidentally removed the trash from the path and ran `sudo rm -rf ~/` I thought for a moment i was changing the directory.

The question is how do I repair the user folders and everything else, icloud and appstore won't login it says `unknown error`.

Comment: I think you need to start with your backup.

Comment: @SolarMike Unfortunately I don't have any backups, but i managed to get it working by logging out and in again.

Comment: Why would you have needed sudo in order to empty~/.Trash ?

Comment: On MacOS 10.13 and newer you might have a backup in TimeMachine even if you don't know it, check [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373056/107414)  and [this link in particular](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015) for details.

Comment: @MarcWilson according to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233481/209035) it supposed to be the best way to remove it, and it did remove it eventually.

Comment: This is a text book case for having a backup if there ever was one.  All I can say is if you have documents in the cloud somewhere, don't synchronize or you will risk losing that too.  I would *create a new account* and allow your cloud to *download* to restore what you lost.  Then go out and buy a USB drive to being a backup regimen.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would try is to log-out and log-in again. In most cases, this will fix your problem.

If not, you have to create a new user account and transfer the data which is left to this new user account. I don't recommend copying the whole Library to the new user account because it could be that your Library is damaged too. I would just copy individual folders like Application Support, Services and so on.

Comment: How does logging out and in again recover data removed by `rm -rf ~`? Also, be specific, things like "copy individual folders like Application Support, Services and so on." won't help a lot if a user doesn't know what to look for.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this answer because there's nothing "dangerous" in here and it doesn't hurt anything to try this.  But I want to post this here so it can be understood what logging in/out does.  When you log in, a number of LaunchAgents run and if the files they use like plists don't exist, it will be created as new.  You may be asked to (re)authenticate to a service and it will save your credentials thus getting you back into a service (like mail) but under no circumstance is this considered data recovery.  Your previous settings and preferences are gone and will have to be recreated.